# Python - Remove Aphostrophe and cut string

Tags: python

I want to define a function which removes aphostrophe but also what letters it has after aphostrophe too:

for example:

```
remove_aph("What's")
>>>What
remove_aph("Kha'Zix")
>>>Kha
```

Comment: `def remove_aph(word): return word.split("'")[0]`

Comment: Sorry that returns an array. Thats why i create a topic

Comment: Mind the little `[0]` at the end, it would return you the `str` element at the 0th index.

Comment: exactly thank you. My bad

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index` to get the position:

```
>>> s= "What's"
>>> s[:s.index("'")] # this is assuming that you always have a single quote
# "What"
```

Alternatively, you could split on `'` and get the first value

```
>>> s.split("'")[0]
# "What"
```

Comment: second one is what im looking for. as @ZdaR mentioned recieve array. Thanks didn't know i can select first element like that im so new

Answer (score 1):

```
def remove_aph(word):
   return word.split("'")[0]
```